# Audience Guid is different in site collection backup and restoration?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, backup, restore, audience-targeting

I have a Site collection with several list and documents, I have enabled the Audience targeting for those and targeted some audience for some documents. I took back of the site collection and I restored into a different machine. Here I found audience GUID is different from a backup machine. So audience targeting is not working in our custom web parts. I am not sure why this happening. Please advise me about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you restored it to different farm then yes target audience ID should be different. You have to reconfigure the audience on restore sites.